# How are polymorphic fields handled in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb

Say I have a field `A` with values:

- `"some string"`
- `12`
- `["I'm an array"]`
- `{"great": "also an object"}`

How does this work? (if it does at all)

I.e: In Elasticsearch for example an implicit field mapping is created under the covers based on the first value that comes in for said field, if an explicit mapping doesn't exist.

E.g.: if `"some string"` comes in as first value for `A`, `A` is assumed to contain strings from then on. If afterwards anything that can't be coerced to a string is persisted, the insert will fail.

Since RethinkDb is schemaless (no field mappings), does the same logic apply here?

Or, as an alternative, nothing at all is assumed on type, and polymorphic values can live happily side by side in the same field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing at all is assumed on type, same field can have different type. They can live happily side by side. When doing query, if you needs some special decision based on type of field, you can use something like `branch` and `typeOf`, or do some pre-processing with `map`.

You can try this in data exploerer:

```
r.table('user').insert({f: "12"});
r.table('user').insert({f: 12})  ;
r.table('user').insert({f: [12]});
r.table('user').insert({f: {v: 12}});
```